# How to continue parsing after an error in Antlr 4.4

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

Does any one knows if there is an `ErrorStrategy` on Antlr4.4 to continue parsing after an error is found, i need to show all the errors found in the program but Antlr stop parsing after the first error is found, im using the `DefaultErrorStrategy`.

This is my input, I should get error ond line 2 3 and 6 but it only reports the error on line 2.

```
class Program {
    bool
    bool test
    int prueba ;
    int prueba ;
    int test;
    bool    prueba
}
```

The error is:

```
line 2:1 mismatched input 'bool' expecting {'boolean', 'int', 'void', '}'}
 bool
 ^^^^
```

Comment: Err... error recovery is the default strategy. How about you post your grammar? In your case I guess the recovery failed because you have 2 errors in 2 contiguous lines and it doesn't know what to do about it.

Comment: It sounds like you forgot to include an explicit EOF symbol at the end of your start rule, which allows ANTLR to stop early if it means avoiding more syntax errors.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski i think you are right, i have tested another program with errors in not 2 contiguous lines and it is reporting the errors properly  

line 2:1 extraneous input 'bool' expecting {'boolean', 'int', 'void', '}'}  
 bool  
 ^^^^  
line 8:4 extraneous input 'bool' expecting {'boolean', 'int', 'void', '}'}   
    bool  prueba;  
    ^^^^  
line 10:1 extraneous input 'into' expecting {'boolean', 'int', 'void', '}'}  
 into test;  
 ^^^^  
  
this is my initial rule  

program: CLASS PROGRAM OPEN_BRACE field_decl* method_decl* CLOSE_BRACE EOF;

Comment: this is my initial rule  

program: CLASS PROGRAM OPEN_BRACE field_decl* method_decl* CLOSE_BRACE EOF;  

So, it will not recover if there are 2 contiguous errors?

Answer (score 2):

Antlr 4's parser error strategy is to drop tokens from the input until it can detect a sane state and then it continues parsing. Looking at your example, while trying to recover maybe it never reaches a sane state before EOF.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like antlr can't recover if there are 2 contiguous error in the program. If the errors are not contiguous it works fine. Thank you very much for your help.